# Intellisense in linq projection after group by

Tags: linq, group-by, linq-to-objects, projection

I have a `Collection<IStatements> statements` which has

```
public interface IStatements
{
    IDocuments Documents { get; set; }
    string StatementDate { get; set; }
} 
public class Documents : IDocuments
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to perform a group by on StatementDate and then do a projection.
When projecting if the group has more then one statement then I would like to club their statement date into 1. The problem is that I don't get Intellisense after groupby

```
 var monthlyStatements = from mStatement in statements
             orderby mStatement.StatementDate descending
             group mStatement by mStatement.StatementDate;
```

I have tried following code

```
var monthlyStatements = from mStatement in statements
           orderby mStatement.StatementDate descending
           group mStatement by mStatement.StatementDate
                   into msStatement
                         select new 
                                  {
                                   StatementDate = 
                                    mStatement.Documents.Date.,//no Intellisense 
                                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`msStatement` is going to be a *grouping* of `IStatements`, not a *single* `IStatements`. So you can do two things with it:

- Get the `Key` property (which will be the statement date)
- Get the contents of the group (which will each be an `IStatements`)

It's not really clear what you're trying to do with the multiple `IStatements` though.

The reason you haven't got `dStatementDate` any more is because you're using a query continuation; the only thing left is the grouping. Fortunately it's irrelevant here as you can get the statement date from the key; you can remove your "let" clause completely.